# troubles with displaying image in window

Tags: java, swing

I need to choose image with file open dialog and then show it in window. But When I choose image it is not shown in the window.

I've created class which create window with jmenubar and 1 jmenuitem. When I click on menuitem JfileChooser appears and then I choose some file. But then happens nothing.
I think the problem is in actionListener for JFileChooser(ImageFilter is a filter from docs java)

```
public Frame(){
    //create bars and window
    mainframe = new JFrame("Window");
    mainframe.setVisible(true);
    mainframe.setSize(300, 300);
    menubar = new JMenuBar();
    mainer = new JMenu("Menu");
    menubar.add(mainer);
    //create items
    item = new JMenuItem("Open",KeyEvent.VK_T);
    item.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, ActionEvent.ALT_MASK));
    item.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("open image");
    //action listener
    item.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //open file dialog
                    choser = new JFileChooser();
                    choser.addChoosableFileFilter(new ImageFilter());
                    final int returnval = choser.showOpenDialog(menubar);
                    //action listener for JFileChooser
                    choser.addActionListener(
                            new ActionListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                    if (returnval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                                        fc = choser.getSelectedFile();
                                        try{
                                            Panel panel = new ShowImage(fc.getName());
                                            mainframe.getContentPane().add(panel);
                                        }catch(Exception exc){};
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    );
                }
            }
    );
    mainer.add(item);
    mainframe.setJMenuBar(menubar);
}
```

ShowImage class

```
class ShowImage extends Panel{
    BufferedImage image;
    public ShowImage(String imagename) throws IOException {
        File input = new File(imagename);
        image = ImageIO.read(input);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(image,0,0,image.getWidth(),image.getHeight(),null);
    }
}
```

P.S another problem is that it shows nothing until I change size of the window.

Comment: `setVisible()/setSize()` such things must come at the very end, once you had added stuff to your container. Put those things at the end of the constructor, for things to work smoothly after `mainFrame.setJMenuBar(...)`, `setVisible(true)` must come at the very end, after you had added everything. If you don't know that better try to go through the tutorials of Swing again for some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extend [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) instead of `Panel`, and override [paintComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paintComponent%28java.awt.Graphics%29) method, ie:

```
class ShowImage extends JPanel{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        ...
    }
}
```

Also, there is no need to `addActionListener` on `JFileChooser`, just check the return value and act accordingly, ie:

```
final int returnval = choser.showOpenDialog(menubar);
if (returnval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
    ...
}
```

Comment: It would be better to simply use a `JLabel` in a `JScrollPane` to display the image.  No need to override anything & the scroll bars will appear automatically if the image is too large for the size of the assigned area.

Answer (score 2):

Im pretty sure this line will cause problems:

```
Panel panel = new ShowImage(fc.getName());
```

getName() will return the name of the file. So for example if you choose a image with JFileChooser named image.jpg, getName will return "image.jpg". This will make the image only show if the file you select is stored in the root folder of your project. I would change `getName()` to `getAbsoultePath()` which will return the full patch (e.i c:\desktop\image.jpg) which is most likley what you want.

Also as Max points out, you should override paintComponent rather then paint:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){     
   g.drawImage(image,0,0,image.getWidth(),image.getHeight(),null); 
}
```

Comment: *"you should override paintComponent rather then paint:"*  You should also use an `ImageObserver` when one is available.  Exchange `null` for `this` when painting in a component, and you have one.